# Props are not passed down to the child component - redux-form/react

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

My props are not passed down to the child component. I have the following parent component NewProject:

```
...

export class NewProject extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.saveProject = this.saveProject.bind(this);
  }

  saveProject = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{fontSize: 14}} className="container">
          <NewProjectForm
            onSubmit={this.saveProject}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
...
```

And the child component NewProjectForm

```
...
const NewProjectForm = (props) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    pristine,
    reset,
    submitting,
    locale
  } = props;

  console.log(props);

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <RaisedButton labelColor='#ffffff' type="submit" backgroundColor='#86BFC4' label="Save" />
      </form>
    </Form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'newProjectForm'
})(NewProjectForm);
```

When I press the submit button, i get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop
    at checkSubmit (eval at ./node_modules/redux-form/lib/reduxForm.js (http://localhost:3000/main.js:5694:1), <anonymous>:133:11)
    at Form.submit (eval at ./node_modules/redux-form/lib/reduxForm.js (http://localhost:3000/main.js:5694:1), <anonymous>:540:74)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js?:70:16)
```

The error occur because the props are not passed down, but why is that - what am I missing?

Here is the output of the console.log...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You send onSubmit with props and try to use handleSubmit

```
  const {
    handleSubmit, // change to onSubmit
    pristine,
    reset,
    submitting,
    locale
  } = props;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a name mismatch issue:

```
<NewProjectForm
    onSubmit={this.saveProject}
/>
```

You are passing it as `onSubmit` and using it as `handleSubmit`:

```
const {
    handleSubmit, // change this to onSubmit
    pristine,
    reset,
    submitting,
    locale
  } = props;
```

Comment: We even wrote same comment)

Comment: @Andrew haha nice, same solution :)